# Need help opening a url in the phone's default browser

Tags: android, url, browser, android-intent

I'm trying to make test-program that opens a website by pushing a button. I have made a listener and everything, my problem is just that, the url-opening-script makes an error and tells me "Uri cannot be resolved". Here's the script I use to open up an webpage:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));  
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I have the `import android.app.Activity;`, `import android.content.Intent;` and `import android.content.ContentUris;` (maybe the last one isn't needed) so I can't find out what's wrong...

I hope someone knows what I've done wrong, or forgot to import...

P.S. I've used this pages to get to where I am:

[How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/android-open-url-from-code)
[Sending an Intent to browser to open specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Comment: how about importing "android.net.Uri"?

Comment: I did'nt know that. Thanks! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open a URL in Android's web browser from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the Uri class. If you are using Eclipse you can hit ctrl-shift-o to add needed imports, and remove unused ones.

Comment: Thanks to BrennaSoft and bhups! You guys are the best! ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
try this
String url = "http://www.google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
```

if you want import class then Click CTRL+Sift+O to import all required packages in eclipse.