# How to break out of Twitter in-app browser in Android?

Tags: javascript, android, twitter

I have a typical modern web-app, regularly shared on Twitter.
I recently noticed that, when opening our web-app in the Twitter internal browser, localstorage is deactivated, which breaks our app.

How could I break out of the Twitter internal browser and open the page in the default Android browser?

Comment: An example of a site which is able to do so is https://dribbble.com/

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204305/need-help-opening-a-url-in-the-phones-default-browser

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried this but just a suggestion. You could take a look at [this](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) and give it a try.

At the end of the article, it says that the external app won't be invoked if triggered without a user gesture but I believe that the limitation won't be there in case of the In-App browser.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think it isn't quite easy to say Android via a WebView to open the Chrome Browser as this in-app browser could be a lot different.

What you could try, as mentioned in the article [Here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) is to trigger a click on an anchor which is calling an "pseudo" intent and add the fallback_url .

There isn't much details provided but it could be a possible hack / workaround.

In your HTML

```
<a href="intent://url/#Intent;scheme=lala;package=com.google.chrome;S.browser_fallback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fyourappurl.com;end" class="open_me">...</a>
```

And with JS:

```
$(".open_me").trigger("click");
```

According to the article

> Now the URL will get you to zxing.org if the app could not be found, or the link was triggered from JavaScript without user gesture
>   (or for other cases where we don’t launch an external application.)

If you're lucky it will open the fallback_url, but as mentioned before it is a WebView which isn't the same as the Chrome Browser, therefore it is possible that nothing happens.

Answer (score -3):

You can use a iFrame in your HTML like this:

```
<iframe src="url.com" width="900" height=400"></iframe>
```

Comment: It's not clear how iframe can help detect Twitter in-app browser