# How to render a web page using the in-built android browser with the jdk?

Tags: java, android

My app needs to use the in-built **Internet Browser** to render a web page.

How to do this kind of job?

Comment: In your question title you mention the JDK, but it isn't mentioned in your question. What's does your question have to do with the JDK?

Comment: I'm using the android jdk to develop my app.

Comment: @Javanator ,I just accepted many of them a while ago,but seems SO hasn't recalculated it...

Comment: @fms thats good and this the way stackoverflow works. The answer posted below my @samuh is correct . follow the thread mention in the answer and if it helps you then dont forget to accept it

Comment: @Javanator ,seems not,I don't see any logic that chooses which browser to use to render the web page...

Answer (score 2):

Launch an Intent with `ACTION_VIEW` action and pass the URL of your website as Intent data.
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url) might help.

Comment: I don't see there is the logic to control which browser to use ...In my case,only the **Internet Browser** will render it correctly...

Comment: `ACTION_VIEW` is a generic intent; `IntentResolver` will display a chooser Activity to the User in case there are multiple caterers for handling the data. So, if there are multiple browsers user will be given an option to choose from one.

Comment: @sms yes i think you should leave it to choose any available browser. instead of specifying any perticualr. because that could differ in different devices

Comment: But the web page can only be rendered correctly by the **Internet Browser**,and my end users have no technical background,so I need to do this programmatically for them..

Comment: @Javanator ,the **Internet Browser** is shipped with each android phone so it's fine..

Comment: @fms : if you want a specific Application to be invoked, like in your case the Browser app, create a `Component` that identifies the `com.android.browser` package and set it in the Intent object. Note that however, if that component is not found in any device(even due to a name change), your Intent might go unresolved.