# Sharing Map based Location

Tags: android

I have developed an application that shows one's location on a map. How do I go about sharing my current location with others who are using my application? Is it possible to send them a notification to let them know my current location?

Comment: yes, but did you search on the ways of sending notification to other mobile numbers???

Comment: Thanks for the idea. So the notification will be limited to my phone book contacts

Comment: i m saying, that how will you send a notification to any number? did you think of any? well i can think of one and that is "sms".....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A format that I use to send a location is to leverage the `maps.google.com` site, like:

```
"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + loc_x + "," + loc_y + "&iwloc=A"
```

This `String` can be inserted into a SMS or Email message. I found [this site](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters) with some good info for formating a URL to automatically open a map centered on the given coordinates. A possible implementation for SMS could be:

```
String message = 
             "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + loc_x + "," + loc_y + "&iwloc=A";

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message){

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to send an SMS to: " + phoneNumber);
    try {
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error sending an SMS to: " + phoneNumber + " :: " + e);
    }       

}
```

Where `loc_x` and `loc_y` represent lat and lon from a `LocationManager` instance.

Comment: @Android_Virus can you be a bit more specific when you say "not working", are you referring to the URL string or the code snippet? Might be able to help if you provide as much detail as you can.