# how to share google map with current location in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am trying to share google map with my current location in my app(similar to whatsapp), I searched for it but didn't find any solution. Can anybody guide me that how can I start working over it. I don't have any idea that how should I start this.

Comment: Go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842144/sharing-map-based-location?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842144/sharing-map-based-location?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

We need to know how you plan to share this data, but in general you can share your GeoPoint variable that contains your latitude and longitude position on the globe..

```
GeoPoint(int latitudeE6, int longitudeE6) 
      // Constructs a GeoPoint with the given latitude and longitude, measured in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).
```