# how to share the location in mapv2 in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, share

i want to share the Location on click the pin on mapv2. i already implement the popup on press pin but the not idea about the location share. 
so any one can implement in it..

```
     ButtonListener = new PopupWindowTouchListener(popupButton) {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
    //              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button1 clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            String message = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&iwloc=A";
            System.out.println("message...> " + message);
            sendSMS("**********",message);

        }
    }; 


   private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message){

    System.out.println("message..> " + message);
    System.out.println("phoneno..> " + phoneNumber);
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    Log.d("TAG", "Attempting to send an SMS to: " + phoneNumber);
    try {
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
        System.out.println("successfully sent ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error sending an SMS to: " + phoneNumber + " :: " + e);
    }       

}
```

Comment: Go tho this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842144/sharing-map-based-location?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842144/sharing-map-based-location?rq=1)

Comment: Where do you want to share. In what format do you want to share.

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj not sent the message on mobile..

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj put the code..

Comment: Have you added "android.permission.SEND_SMS" permission in the manifest file. If you use KIT KAT android version, read this post http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html to send sms

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj also add the permission ...and not need to run in kit kat..its run below api level 18

Comment: @Android_Virus you cannot send send SMS in KITKAT version. You need to set your application as the default messaging app. Please refer the link I 've mentioned in the above comment for best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marker.getPosition()` will return `LatLng`

```
LatLng latlng = Marker.getPosition();
Double latitude = latlng.latitude;
Double longitude = latlng.longitude;
```

You can manipulate the `latitude` and `longitude` values to construct your data format. And use [Intent chooser](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to share.

**For example** `"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&iwloc=A"` and share it via [SMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)

Comment: Hello when we use this functionality with share intent in that when we share location in wattsup application that time one google default add can bi attached you have any idea to remove this @Vinothkumar Arputharaj

Answer (score 0):

```
    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +latitude+","+longitude;
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String ShareSub = "Here is my location";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, ShareSub);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uri );
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: Could you please explain more details about your code?