# Internet connection in android after pressing a button

Tags: android

I want to load a web page after pressing a button how it is possible in android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Sending an Intent to Browser to open specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you have to write a clicklistener for the button and inside onClick() give the below code :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(give ur website address over here);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

Or in the layout file for the button tag, you give the property `android:onClick` and give its value as the method name.

For eg:

```
android:onClick="openWebsite"
```

and in activity give:

```
public void openWebsite(View view) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(give ur website address over here);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
}
```