# I want to create a downloadable bookmark in the Android market

Tags: android, google-play, bookmarks

I currently have a web app already and I would like to create a bookmark that can be downloaded from the android marketplace (and app store if possible) and it would redirect the user to my web app. I want to know if this is possible and if so how can it be done?

Comment: Note that such apps are frequently ridiculed in Android Market comments and will tend to get lower ratings.

Comment: http://os-code-web.blogspot.com/2011/05/javascript-click-here-to-make-default.html

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own webview app shell around your website:

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Or you can have your app simply launch the default browser with your specific url:

[Sending an Intent to browser to open specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), you can do an iphone app at the same time..