# getting position in a list and then display a web view

Tags: android

Hey I am trying to display a web view if someone clicks on the 5th item in a list.

This is the code:

```
          lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {

            if (position == 5) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(href2_final
                                + "=service&doc_library=ABN01&doc_number="
                                + record_parsed_final
                                + "&line_number=0001&func_code=WEB-FULL&service_type=MEDIA");
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

    });
```

What am I doing wrong? If I delete the IF statement then it will launch the web view when i press any item in the list.

Thanks!

Comment: How many items do you have on the list ?

Comment: loool this is hilarious! position == 5 is definitely the 5th item

Comment: @SherifelKhatib: are you sure? I just tested it, and the first element in the list has a value for `position` of zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code, you must need to select 6th item in your ListView to call startActivity. For more info, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the fifth element is indexed in the position 4.