# How to fetch all the browser names installed on android mobile

Tags: java, android

I am new to android application development.

I want to fetch the list of installed browser names on android mobile through the application.
How can I do that?

Comment: based on your comment on one answer... know that getting the browsing history in all the browsers installed on the device will be much more challenging than just getting a list of the browsers... some (most?) of them may not expose any interface to provide you that data...

Answer (score 3):

I did not test this, but the most obvious way should be to use the PackageManager to find what application / Activity can resolve the Intent to browse a web address.

The function you are looking for is there : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent, int)

The Intent should have action [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) and the data could be "http://www.google.com" or any web URL you would like (as long as it starts with http)

Answer (score 0):

From your question I infer you probably want the user to choose a browser to open a URL?! If you simply want the user to pick one of the installed browsers to open a URL given by your app, you don't have to display a list of them yourself. Android will care about it; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Actually i want identify all the browsers at run time to fetch the browser history in my application.