# Android Webview for videosteams?

Tags: android

I am using a webview to connect to an ip camera. It works when I need snapshots , but i get a white screen when I try to get videostreams. I tried .getPlugins as well. What could be the possible reason?

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://<ipaddress>/videostream.cgi?user=&pwd=");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call Browser activity and set specific URL by intent. Take a look here: [Sending an Intent to browser to open specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)