# How do I download a file via default Android Downloader?

Tags: android, file, debugging, download, android-2.2-froyo

How can I download files using Android downloader? (The downloader that WebBrowser is using that too).

I tried something like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("MyUrl"));
startActivity(i);
```

Any better way?

**Edit**

I am using Android 2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `HttpUrlConnection` to do this on Android 2.2 and below. There is a very detailed [**tutorial**](http://progrnotes.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-android.html) on the internet that shows you how to do this (with a progress dialog box too).

Remember you **must** use an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` to ensure that you do not block the UI thread during the actual download!

Comment: Thank you, But "How can I download files using default Android downloader?". I think I should use my own solution.

Comment: If you are working on a device that runs Android 2.2 or below, you can't. The default downloader was introduced in 2.3 and thus earlier versions won't recognize it.

Answer (score 20):

Here you go.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadManagerActivity extends Activity {
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                            view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("url for file to download"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

    }

    public void showDownload(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `android.permission.internet` in manifest.

Comment: great answer.  actually I didn't knew such a service exists.  is it a sticky broadcast?

Comment: Sorry not Sure about it :) .You can Accept this answer if it solve your problem,as it will help others :)

Comment: @VipulShah Thank you, But DownloadManager is introduced in Android 2.3 and I'm using Android 2.2. So what is the solution?

Comment: @Kermia: On Android 2.2 and lower, you download the file yourself using `HttpUrlConnection` or `HttpClient`.

Comment: Can we download youtube video using the httpurlconnection

Comment: @Bhupendra No,you cant

Comment: do you know how can i download youtube

Comment: http://code4andy.blogspot.in/2013/12/android-default-downloader-to-downaload.html

Answer (score 6):

If you want to download it onto the user's SD card from an URL, you can just open it in the phone's default internet browser.

```
String url = "https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

[(Code from this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

The android browser will then start and the file (in this case an image) will be downloaded.

Comment: In My sony xepria phone the.The image is shown in the browser it self.What I want is after firing intent when download  starts it should move to my app.

Comment: If you're trying to download an image then the browser will open the image and view it. This method is meant for binary files such as .zip. I recommend you use Vipul Shah's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cant perform network operation in the main thread. You can look up to [this](https://github.com/amit-appstudioz/AndroidFileDownloaderModule) repository to download file.

Comment: Hi Amit, maybe you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)