# android downloader, how can i customize

Tags: java, android

I can use the `android downloader` to download files. and the code is **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10950971/1140321)**

By default android stores the files in `download` directory. How can I specify the path where it should be downloaded? If this is not possible, I plan to copy the file in sd card and I want to delete the src file(the file in the `download` folder. But I am unable to delete the file from the `download` folder. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setDestinationInExternalPublicDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Request request = new Request(
            Uri.parse("url for file to download"));
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (String dirType, String subPath);
    long enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

this method may help you!

Comment: dirType:the directory type to pass to getExternalFilesDir(String),
subPath:the path within the external directory, including the destination filename

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/download";
```

could you change the "/download" part? I think that would save it onto external storage though