# android how to navigate a web site on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button

I want to navigate to a facebook fan page when I click on a button in my adroid application.
I am new to android. Can anybody help me to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Sending an Intent to Browser to open specific URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Comment: Have you tried anyone of the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you try like this.

```
String url = "http://www.facebook.com/yourfanpagename";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Place above code inside of your button click.

Answer (score 1):

Just use intents for it.
Here is an example,

In your button's click event:

```
// Open Website
    Intent intent;

    try {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com/yourPage"));
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception Caught", e.toString());
    }
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Using intent to open the browser, like this:

   ```
   String url = "http://www.facebook.com/your_page";
   Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

   i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
   startActivity(i);
   ```
2. Use a webview in your layout and open a link in application.It is more preferable.

You can find the link [here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html) to implement it.