# is there a good way to open a webpage automatically after an app starts?

Tags: android, web

I guess the question is the description. Plain, simple... How can I do this in a simple and easy way? I have done this before in regular Java, but android being so similar and yet soooo different seems to have a different way of doing so.

-Thanks!

Comment: I don't honestly see why it should be so similar: Android is a completely different platform than a desktop..

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url

But Ahmad's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with this in your `OnCreate()` method:

```
Intent openLink = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("yourLink"));
startActivity(openLink);
```

Or if you don't want to open it in a web browser you can load it in a WebView like this:

```
WebView myWebView  = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.yourWebView);
myWebView.loadUrl("yourLink");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

but then don't forget to create a WebViewClient:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

     @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
}
```