# App crashes when I add an onClickListener to ImageView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, onclicklistener

I have an ImageView in my app and I want it to open a certain website when it is clicked. I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything right but it still won't work. The app crashes as soon as I click the ImageView.

```
ImageView banner = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.banner);
banner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openUrl = new Intent();
            openUrl.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            openUrl.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
            openUrl.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
            startActivity(openUrl);
        }
    });
```

Logcat file:

```
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=www.google.com }
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at si.dvanadva.evanturist.CheckpointsActivity$2.onClick(CheckpointsActivity.java:323)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-26 21:53:49.481: E/AndroidRuntime(25479):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
  openUrl.setData(Uri.parse("www.google.com"));
```

by

```
  openUrl.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
```

More info @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Edit:

```
    String url = "www.google.com";
    if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
    {
         url = "http://" + url;
    }
    else
    {
    Intent openUrl = new Intent();
    openUrl.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    openUrl.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    openUrl.setData(Uri.parse(url));      
    startActivity(openUrl);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Matthew check if your url has `http` or `https` before itself.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to ensure your `URL` is correctly formatted (prefix is important):

```
http://www.google.com
```

not

```
www.google.com
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url) for an example.

Comment: `openUrl.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);` has nothing to do with the crash. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html. scroll down and check `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to open the website in a browser window? If so, remove the CATEGORY. I'm pretty sure that's only for WebViews.