# Intent to open url results in wrong url on browser

Tags: android, url, android-intent, uri

I am trying to open a URL in a browser using an intent.

My code is

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.onair99.com"));
startActivity(i);
```

This will result in an error on any browser I have tried since the browser tries to open something like this:

```
http://http//onair99.com//
```

As far as I have tried, I only have encountered the problem with this specific URL.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks.

Comment: try removing 'http://' from the origin url?

Comment: Then I get "ActivityNotFoundException" (AndroidRuntime(1427): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=www.somewebsite.com })

Comment: I copy pasted your code and its working absolutely fine in my Samsung Galaxy Young. Should you change any browser settings itself ?

Comment: @suitianshi what in case if origin url has `https://` ??

Comment: @VnyKumar I have tried on different devices and the emulator as well. I always get the same error...

Comment: What is the exact url you are trying to reach. Does it start with `https`? because your code should work normally.

Comment: No it doesn't start with https. And it's not related to the url since I get the same error if I try to open `http://www.google.com`.

Comment: I updated my question. I have actually found out that this only happens when the specific url I am trying to open which is `www.onair99.com`. Anybody can try?

Comment: It is a website issue. I will have to hear the site administrator. Thanks you everybody.

Answer (score 2):

do as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

```
String url = "http://www.somewebsite.com";
```

In production level code, you may like to check if the url begins with http or https... Would be better to check

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))  
  url = "http://" + url;

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

Here's the [documentation of Intent.ACTION_VIEW.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. The address I'm feeding to the intent is a constant and I know it starts with http.

Comment: if you are sure then it wont go inside if block and instead will directly go to intent part. what issue are you getting when you do startactivity using this intent code?

Comment: I updated my question. I have actually found out that this only happens when the specific url I am trying to open which is `www.onair99.com`. Anybody can try?

Comment: then it is possible issue of .htaccess file on server. in that it is all defined how a request is to be handled. It is no issue with your android code. i would suggest to try with http:// onair99.com. Kept space as it is converting it into href.

Comment: I still get error if I use the space as you said. Now the browser tries to open `%20onair99.com`

Comment: It is a website issue. I will have to hear the site administrator. Thanks you everybody.

Comment: space was kept for writing purpose only ... in code you have to use without space.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

main.xml

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" Go to link" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

---

MyAndroidAppActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.onair99.com"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }

        });

    }

}
```

---

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mkyong.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MyAndroidAppActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. The address I'm feeding to the intent is a constant and I know it starts with http.

Comment: Hey!You got the solution or not?

Comment: No...I'm starting to think I'm screwing up somewherelse in my code. I have read everywhere on the internet that this is the correct way to start the intent. Changing address/browser/device doesn't help at all...so it must be something in my code...

Comment: then try to create new progect see i send one link download the example and see its working or not

Comment: I updated my question. I have actually found out that this only happens when the specific url I am trying to open which is `www.onair99.com`. Anybody can try?

Comment: hii i update my answer and i also confirm with my device and emulator after apply this code you still didn't get solution than you please check emulator/dvice internet connection available or not.

Comment: do you get the same problem opening that url? I can't try your code now. I'll do it as soon as I get home. Thanks

Comment: It is a website issue. I will have to hear the site administrator. Thanks you everybody.