# Is there a way to get information from the web browser in Android?

Tags: android, browser, payment

I would like to create a charity application where if the users were to press the 'Donate' button, their browser would open up a link to a 3rd-party crowdfunding website where they would donate some amount for that project (or choose to exit the app or whatever!). How do I get to know what amount they have donated (or not!) from the browser so that this data can be used for that member's stats, etc.

Comment: use intent to browser for opening the website http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use `webView`

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickLister()
 @overide
 public void onClick(View v) {
WebView mWebView=(WebView)_findViewById(R.id.webView);
mWebview .loadUrl("url for third party app");
        setContentView(mWebview );
});
```

or you can use intent

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickLister()
 @overide
 public void onClick(View v) {
WString url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
});
```