# Starting Android Browsers' Private Activities using Intent URLs

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentfilter, android-browser

first of all i have to admit that im a newbie in Android, but we know that in android we can't start private activities of applications by another application . unless they're set to android:exported=true in their `intent-filter` or they are made for `implicit` calls .
but we should be able to start private Activities from withing the application . and when it comes to browsers (specially in android) we can use `Intent URLs` to start a private Activity of the browser .

i found some Activities in Opera Mobile, and the problem is i just cant run them using Intent URL, and i have no idea what am i doing wrong in this .

for example there is a Activity in opera called `OperaMainActivity` (or another called `OperaStartActivity`) im trying to start them like this :

```
intent:#Intent;component=com.opera.browser/com.opera.android.OperaMainActivity;end
```

or

```
intent:#Intent;component=com.opera.browser/com.opera.android.OperaStartActivity;end
```

but none of these will start the Activity Called.

though i can still start `AdMarvelActivity` which is a private as well :

```
"intent:#Intent;S.url=https://google.com;component=com.opera.browser/com.admarvel.android.ads.AdMarvelActivity;end";
```

here is how OperaMain Activity defined in `AndroidManifest` :

```
<activity ns0:label="@string/app_name_title" ns0:name="com.opera.android.OperaMainActivity" ns0:launchMode="singleTask" ns0:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ns0:windowSoftInputMode="10" />
```

and there is no `intent-filter` for it .

and this is how `AdMarvelActivity` defined in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity ns0:theme="@*ns0:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" ns0:name="com.admarvel.android.ads.AdMarvelActivity" ns0:process=":helper" ns0:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

i see no major difference between these two . what am i doing wrong ?!

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url

Comment: no . its about starting browsers public activities which could be called from another applications . im looking for explicity calling private activities from withing the browser itself, of course using Intent URL Schemes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Vulnerable Handling of Intent URL Scheme](http://www.mbsd.jp/Whitepaper/IntentScheme.pdf) has been known since a long time and most of the popular browsers (like chrome, opera) have fixed this bug. However alternative android browsers still have this vulnerability.

I tried the attack on the current version of Opera Mobile (v37) and thankfully its not working. You must be running it on an older apk.

If you are interested in testing this attack on alternative browsers, you can follow this talk : [All Your Browsers Belong To Us](http://infiltratecon.com/archives/all_your_browsers_belong_to_us_Benjamin_Watson.pdf); which demostrates this attack on Dolphin Browser and Mercury Browser.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i know about the attack . but my question is a bit different . im asking if i can start private activities, then why i cant start the activity provided in the question . i wanna know how to run them . i mean if i can start AdMarvelActivity then why i cant start others ?! am i writing the intent url wrong ?!

Comment: I agree that if `AdMarvelActivity` can be run then others should also be runnable. It might be that you are missing some intent extras which are mandatory for the activity to start. You can intercept or log all intents via `adb logcat | fgrep -i intent` and check if the problem is with the intent being fired or received. What version of Opera Mobile are you trying this. Please share the apk and Intent url that you tried.

Comment: the adb command works really good for monitoring . i found that the problem was in some version's of browsers (specially the new ones) filtering the component in intent url's . if you have notices in the codes they set the intent.setComponent(null) immediately after parseURI . so we cant call the private activities using component . is there any other way to start them ?

Comment: Nope I don't think starting private activities would be possible without component. `HOST/URI-path#Intent;package=[string];action=[string];category=[string];component=[string];scheme=[string];end;`. `package`,`action`,`category` are not exploitable unless the target code has explicitly made the mistake of starting private activities on certain `action` or added a wrong `category` to some activity. The talk "All your Browsers Belong to Us` discusses about exploiting `scheme` but its not for starting private activities.

Comment: thank alot, then i have to search for vulnerability where parseURL happends to see if they made any mistake .