# How to scan a QR code that is a URL and open the link

Tags: android, qr-code

I have the below code that works by scanning the qr code but instead of showing the link I want it to open the url how do I change this to do that?

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents()==null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, result.getContents(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {

            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an Intent to browser to open specific URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)