# How to open xml file with chrome using intent?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

I need to open an XML file stored in a String variable. I want to open it with chrome without saving in the phone storage, is this possible?

I can open chrome using intents but now I need to load the xml file.

```
public void onClickOpen(View v){

    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url

Comment: @m0skit0 that is not what I was looking for, I don't want to open a URI. I need to open a XML file stored in a String variable

Comment: A URI is valid for any location, hence the U meaning UNIVERSAL.

Comment: @m0skit0 ok but I don't want to save the file using phone storage...I asked if it is possible to do without messing with phone storage

Comment: where is the file stored? from where do you want to open it?

Comment: So you want to pass the XML string to Chrome? I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do in a webview it can be done in this way

String mString = `"<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>"`;

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,mString,"text/html","UTF-8",null);
```

Comment: A webview is not a browser