# Open pdf file on android studio and open a black screen pdf

Tags: java, android, pdf, provider

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfCGB.png).Try to open pdf file that is stored in the emulator and through file provider. The problem is that the pdf opens up but its content is empty(black screen). Thank You!

```
            File item = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/theoretical_computer_science_cheat_sheet.pdf");
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this[enter image description here][1],getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".share",item);
            //Uri uri = getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".share",item);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri,"application/pdf");

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            try {
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // Instruct the user to install a PDF reader here, or something
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load that pdf file first?  I suspect your PDF reader will load by itself.

Comment: what do you mean by loading the pdf? i appreciate your comment.

Comment: >String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);

Comment: refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

Comment: i think this will not work. My pdf is already inside the emulator storage